# Is it a coffeescript bug? Destructuring and Existential Operator

Tags: coffeescript

following coffeescript code:

```
{ baz } = @foo.bar?
```

produces:

```
var baz;
baz = (this.foo.bar != null).baz;
```

but I expect:

```
var ref, baz;
if ((ref = this.foo.bar) != null) {
  baz = ref.baz;
}
```

Is it a bug or an expected behavior?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you expecting `{ baz } = @foo.bar?` to be more-or-less equivalent to `baz = @foo.bar?.baz`?

Comment: Hey, I expect `baz = @foo.bar?.baz` be equal `{ baz } = @foo.bar?`

Comment: Looks correct to me `{baz} = qux` is shortcut for `baz = qux.baz`. Since `qux ` is `@foo.bar?` you get what you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've confused the unary `?` operator with the binary `?.` operator.

The right-hand side of this expression:

```
baz = @foo.bar?.baz
```

...uses the binary `?.` operator. As you know, it returns the value of the subsequent property if it exists and `null` otherwise (and short-circuits evaluation of further properties).

On the other hand, the RHS of this expression:

```
{ baz } = @foo.bar?
```

...uses the unary `?` operator. It returns `false` if its operand (the preceding expression) is `null` or `undefined`, and `true` otherwise.

This is a really easy mistake to make; you can see someone ask the same question in [this CoffeeScript issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/4486). Compounding the problem, the CoffeeScript docs don't even give these two operators different names. They call `?` the ["existential operator"](http://coffeescript.org/#existential-operator) and `?.` the "accessor variant of the existential operator."